# Understanding the gamma function in the context of Jitsuro Nagura's Proof

Tags: prime-numbers, gamma-function

In 1952, Jitsuro Nagura published a classic proof that shows that for $n \ge 25$, there is always a prime between $n$ and $\frac{6n}{5}$.

For those interested the paper itself can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210309131118/https://projecteuclid.org/DPubS/Repository/1.0/Disseminate?view=body&id=pdf_1&handle=euclid.pja/1195570997).

I'm going through this short proof and I am immediately unclear on the first point.  I would greatly appreciate it if someone can explain the details of the equation below:

$\frac{\Gamma'}{\Gamma}(s) = \int_{0}^∞(\frac{e^{-t}}{t} - \frac{e^{-st}}{1-e^{-t}})dt$ when $s > 0$

From the Wikipedia article on the gamma function is:

$\Gamma(s) = \int_{0}^∞t^{s-1}e^{-t}dt$

and also from Wikipedia, the [polygamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function) is:

$\frac{\Gamma'}{\Gamma}(s) = \psi(s) = \int_0^∞\frac{te^{-st}}{1-e^{-t}}dt$

I am interested in understanding how Nagura arrived at this first expression in the proof.

Comment: I think you may have simply misread Wikipedia. $\frac{\Gamma'}{\Gamma}(s)$ is the *digamma function* with [known integral representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Integral_representations).

Comment: The identity in Nagura's paper is in [section 6.3.21](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_259.htm) of the treatise by Abramowitz and Stegun and the derivative of a formula in [section 6.1.50](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_258.htm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identity in Nagura's paper is in [section 6.3.21](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_259.htm) of the treatise by Abramowitz and Stegun, and the derivative of a formula in [section 6.1.50](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_258.htm).